# iconForFile:appPath] gives blank images for some applications

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I use

```
[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] iconForFile:appPath]
```

to get the images in the application .icns (as defined in the application Info.plist), but for some applications this image is simply a blank/white image? If I write the NSImage I get from the workspace to a file, it contains all the images in the correct resolution but they are all blank/white??

I have absolutly no clue to why this is happening, any input will be appriciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would check if the path is correct, or you could check the result with

```
NSImage *image = [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] iconForFile:appPath]

if([image isValid]){ 
    NSLog(@"Error, image is not valid"); 
}
```